# I am not able to add columns in XML Publisher report

Tags: oracle-apps, oracle-bi, oracle-xml-publisher

I am unable to add columns after loading XML file in Oracle BI Publisher. Getting below screen. Any advise?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using a data definition (data template) within your report template.
Data definiton should be used to create an XML data file and you have to upload the XML data file in the word template.

Data definition contains at minimum a SQL query and data structure. Data structure is kind of specification to create your XML data file based on SQL query.

With your data definition, you will create many XML data files to test your report template.

Using your XML data file, you will be able to add fields.